# react ref hook not giving required result

Tags: reactjs

I want to save clientWidth and clientHeight of content element with use of react ref hook.
But whenever I console ref.current unexpected result is showing

[image]

```
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(ref.current)
}, [ref]);

return (
    <div className="App">
      <Layout>
        <TopBar {...props} />
        <Layout>
          <SideBar {...props} />
          <Content
            ref={ref}
            id="main-layout"
          >
            <App />
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    </div>
```

Comment: The answer depends on what `Content` component code looks like. Can you provide the code for that component?

Comment: @Gandzal `Content` component is react component used from antd library

Answer (score 1):

the return value of useRef function is never changed. so if you want to watch the change of the ref, try as below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(ref.current)
}, [ref.current]);
```